# unable to include potential exec

Tags: javascript, html, apache

We have a html file in our application where in head tag we are using

```
<script language="javascript" src="/javascript/page.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
  <!--#include virtual="/folderpath/abc.js"-->
</script>
```

After loading the html file and if I see view source I found the below error
"An error occurred while processing this directive"
and in apache errors log I am getting "unable to include potential exec abc.js  in parsed file ....."

I modified httpd.conf of apache server by adding the below after browsing google

```
<Directory /folderpath/>
  Options +Includes +ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

But I didn't find any change. I am not sure what I am missing.
Can anyone help me in this regard.

Comment: Can anyone help me on this issue

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem with a file served by Apache 2.4 that used:

```
<!--#include virtual="example.sql">
```

The file was in a directory tree that fell under this rule:

```
<Directory /home/*/public_html>
    Options MultiViews Indexes FollowSymLinks IncludesNoExec
</Directory>
```

That made sense as a default, but I wanted to override it for the files that were below `/home/some_user/public_html`. Adding the following to the Apache 2.4 configuration worked and allowed the #include to work.

```
<Directory /home/some_user/public_html>
    AllowOverride All
    Options -IncludesNOEXEC +Includes
</Directory>
```

See [Apache 2.4 mod_include](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_include.html)

Interestingly, the file worked under Apache2.2, so I wonder if the rules changed. I hope this works for you!

Not long after, I found an alternative solution, which works for .sql files, but might not be appropriate for .js files. It also explains the difference between Apache 2.2 and Apache 2.4. In Apache 2.2, the default `httpd.conf` file had:

```
DefaultType text/plain
```

Which is why I had no trouble including .sql files. But that directive was removed in Apache 2.4. So I fixed the problem by adding the following:

```
<FilesMatch "\.sql$">
    ForceType text/plain
</FilesMatch>
```

See [Apache 2.4 ForceType](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#forcetype)